# MS Sql Splitting Specific column by sub string

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, substring

I am trying write a query to split and join a specific column by sub string. Not sure how to achieve it

```
    Create table #tmp1
    (
    ID bigint,
    Code  varchar(10)
    )
    insert into #tmp1 values(1,'')
    insert into #tmp1 values(2,'DCBA')
    insert into #tmp1 values(3,'BACD')
    insert into #tmp1 values(4,'ABCD')
    select * from #tmp1
    select
    ID,
    * from #tmp1 a
```

I would like to have my end result as

```
1   
2   DCBA    D   1
2   DCBA    C   2
2   DCBA    B   3
2   DCBA    A   4
3   BACD    B   1
3   BACD    A   2
3   BACD    C   3
3   BACD    D   4
4   ABCD    A   1        
4   ABCD    B   2    
4   ABCD    C   3 
4   ABCD    D   4
```

I have tried sql substring but could not finalise it

Comment: sorry for the type,edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive CTE might be the simplest solution:

```
with cte as (
      select id, code, stuff(code, 1, 1, '') as rest, left(code, 1) as letter, 1 as lev
      from #tmp1
      union all
      select id, code, stuff(rest, 1, 1, '') as rest, left(rest, 1) as letter, lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select id, code, letter, lev
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bccc4e546e552d67579d17cbccc96e52) is a db<>fiddle.

Actually, here is a slightly simpler version:

```
with cte as (
      select id, code, left(code, 1) as letter, 1 as lev
      from tmp1
      union all
      select id, code, substring(code, lev, 1) as letter, lev + 1
      from cte
      where lev < len(code)
     )
select id, code, letter, lev
from cte;
```

Comment: First query works, second one dint exactly. Thanks for the help


with cte as (
      select id, code, stuff(code, 1, 1, '') as rest, left(code, 1) as letter, 1 as lev
      from #tmp1
      union all
      select id, code, stuff(rest, 1, 1, '') as rest, left(rest, 1) as letter, lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select id, code, letter, lev
from cte order by id,code ,lev;

Comment: @Dilip . . . If your strings exceed 100 characters, then you will need to add `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)`.